# Left orderable linear groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ordered-groups

Are all torsion-free finitely generated linear groups over $\mathbb{C}$ left orderable? In particular, are torsion-free congruence subgroups of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ left orderable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is no for congruence subgroups of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for $n \geq 3$.  This is a theorem of Dave Witte-Morris; see

MR1198459 (95a:22014) 
Witte, Dave(1-MIT)
Arithmetic groups of higher Q-rank cannot act on 1-manifolds. (English summary) 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 122 (1994), no. 2, 333–340.

Comment: There is a folk conjecture that a discrete, torsion free group with Kazhdan's property (T), cannot be left orderable.

Comment: My own conjecture would be that there exists a nontrivial left-orderable group with Property T. Some little evidence comes from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/156778/14094): left-orderable is compatible with some weak form of Property T. Also the evidence in the opposite direction is not convincing to me: arithmetic lattices were initially seen as prototypical examples of Property T groups, but they're only some very special (though important) examples. Same for local indicability, and subgroups of diffeomorphism groups, which are only very special instances of left-orderable groups.